# Python y flask no muestran valores de una base de datos, utilizando cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Nametable')

Tags: python, base-de-datos, xampp, flask

estoy teniendo utilizando flask, python, mysqlworkbench y xampp, y tengo problemas cuando se llama cur.execute('SELECT * FROM registros') porque no se visualiza la lista de usuarios que tiene la base, no encuentro cual puede ser el error que hace esto no suceda. Ya descarte que sea un tema de la base porque el  login se puede realizar.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, redirect, request,  Response, session, url_for, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL, MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"]='localhost'
app.config["MYSQL_USER"]='root'
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"]='123'
app.config["MYSQL_DB"]='tudepto'
app.config["MYSQL_CURSORCLASS"]='DictCursor'
mysql=MySQL(app)

#LOGIN

@app.route('/acceso-login', methods= ["GET","POST"])
def login():

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'txtCorreo' in request.form and 'txtPassword' in request.form:
        _correo = request.form ['txtCorreo']
        _password = request.form ['txtPassword']

        cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = %s AND password = %s',(_correo, _password,))
        account = cur.fetchone()
        print(account)

        if account:
            session['logueado'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id'] #sesioin id generaba error porque tenia dos iguales
            session['id_rol'] = account['id_rol']

            if session['id_rol'] == 1:
                return render_template('admin.html')
            elif session['id_rol'] == 2:
                return render_template('usuario.html')
        else:
            return render_template('index.html',mensaje="Usuario O Contraseña Incorrectas")
        


@app.route('/prueba')
def prueba():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM registros')
    dato = cur.fetchall()
    print(dato)  # Imprime los datos en la consola

    return render_template('prueba.html', registros = dato)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key="xxx"
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=500, threaded=True)
```

prueba.html

```
{% if registros %} <!-- Indica que existe 'registros' -->
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Nº Apartamento</th>
            <th>Monto de Administración</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for mostrar in registros %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{mostrar.id}}</td>
            <td>{{mostrar.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{mostrar.email}}</td>
            <td>{{mostrar.apartamento}}</td>
            <td>{{mostrar.monto}}</td>
            <td>{{mostrar.estado}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
    {% else %}
<p>No hay datos</p>
{% endif %}
```

No se si es posible que la versión que este utilizando de python (3.11.4) pueda tener errores. Cuando se corre python en la terminal de visual studio no genera errores, simplemente actualiza la pagina

Comment: ¿Se imprime _dato_? ¿Se muestra _No hay datos_ en el html?

Comment: no se imprime el dato, además no es posible ver si se están recibiendo los datos de la web en la consola/terminal de visual.

Comment: ¿E intentaste capturar los errores, por si los hay?